# Why is the Ubuntu 22.04 reboot sequence stopping?

Tags: reboot

I have completed the update to Ubuntu 22.04 but get the following message when rebooting:

```
mphilander@Mphilander: ~$
```

How do I continue the rebooting process after this line?

Marc

Comment: That's a command line prompt. Why you got there is indicated by earlier messages.

Comment: From the "`mphilander@Mphilander: ~$`" prompt, you're logged in as user `mphilander` on a system named "`Mphilander`", with your `$HOME` directory (`~`) as your current directory. You are NOT `root`. For some reason, your GUI failed to start. Read `man less` about paging through multi line results. Look at the startup logs `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To clarify your issue, and to confirm, you installed the Desktop version of Ubuntu, and not the Server version, correct?